# Prove or disprove statements with "infinitely often" and limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, statistics, proof-writing, independence

I have these statements I need to (dis)prove. However, I am stuck with them. Any help is much appreciated.

1. Suppose that $(X_i:i\ge 1)$ are independent. Then $P(X_∙\text{ i.o.})=0$ if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty P(X_i)<\infty.$
2. Suppose that $(X_i:i\ge 1)$ are independent and that the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}\prod_{i=1}^n P(X^c_i)$ exists and is non-zero. Then $P(X_∙\text{ i.o.})=0$.
3. Suppose that $X_i \cap X_j=\emptyset$ for all $i\ne j$  and that $P(X_∙ \text{ i.o.})=0$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(X_i)< \infty$.

Progress: $P(X_∙\text{ i.o.})= \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{i=n}^{\infty}X_i$.

I know that statement $1$ is true, but I am unable to do the rest. Please help.

Comment: Which lemma do you think this is it related to?

Comment: @nejimban Is it the Borel Cantelli Lemma?

Comment: Yes. (1) is exactly Borel-Cantelli lemma; (2) is just saying that $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n^c)>0\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n)<\infty;$$ for (3), do you think the statement is true or false?

Comment: @nejimban I am a bit unsure with 1, due to the words "If and only if". I think that 2 and 3 is true. Please confirm for me? Thanks!

Comment: For (1), independence allows you to use the second part of Borel-Cantelli lemma. (2) is correct; (3) is false (consider $X_n=\{T=n\}$ for some well-chosen random variable $T$).